# C++11 vector of shared pointers and memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory, c++11

The main program worker.cpp contains:

```
    unique_ptr<c_job> job;
    ...(loop)
        job.reset(new c_xcol_job);
    ...(end loop)
    ...
```

Class c_xcol_job contains:

```
    c_pack pack;
```

Class c_pack contains:

```
shared_ptr<c_imago> ref;
```

Class c_imago contains:

```
vector<shared_ptr<c_pixel>> pixel;
```

The vector is filled in imago.h with:

```
91    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
92      shared_ptr<c_pixel_imago> px_buffer = make_shared<c_pixel_imago>();
93        px_buffer->v[0] = 0;
94        px_buffer->v[1] = 1;
95        pixel.push_back(px_buffer);
96    };
```

Class c_pixel contains:

```
class c_pixel {
    public: double D;
...
```

And class c_pixel_imago contains:

```
class c_pixel_imago : public c_pixel {
    public: double v[2];
...
```

This seems to cause a memory leak. This is the output of valgrind:

```
==7252== 9,437,184 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 543 of 544
==7252==    at 0x4C2C7A7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7252==    by 0x421905: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:94)
==7252==    by 0x420932: std::_Vector_base<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> > >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /worker.exe)
==7252==    by 0x420A9D: void std::vector<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> > >::_M_emplace_back_aux<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> >(std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>&&) (vector.tcc:405)
==7252==    by 0x41FA10: void std::vector<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> > >::emplace_back<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> >(std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>&&) (vector.tcc:102)
==7252==    by 0x41E7F5: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<c_pixel> > >::push_back(std::shared_ptr<c_pixel>&&) (stl_vector.h:900)
==7252==    by 0x412843: c_imago::import(std::string, std::string, double) (imago.h:95)
==7252==    by 0x4120CC: c_imago::getd2(std::string) (imago.h:48)
==7252==    by 0x41A2FE: c_xcol_job::launch() (xcol_job.h:42)
==7252==    by 0x41B96D: main (worker.cpp:142)
==7252== 
==7252== 46,094,112 bytes in 480,147 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 544 of 544
==7252==    at 0x4C2C7A7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7252==    by 0x422D7E: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<c_pixel_imago, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:94)
==7252==    by 0x42295F: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<c_pixel_imago, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<c_pixel_imago, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:353)
==7252==    by 0x422407: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<c_pixel_imago, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, c_pixel_imago*, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:522)
==7252==    by 0x4219B5: std::__shared_ptr<c_pixel_imago, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:997)
==7252==    by 0x4209E9: std::shared_ptr<c_pixel_imago>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago> const&) (shared_ptr.h:317)
==7252==    by 0x41F937: std::shared_ptr<c_pixel_imago> std::allocate_shared<c_pixel_imago, std::allocator<c_pixel_imago>>(std::allocator<c_pixel_imago> const&) (shared_ptr.h:599)
==7252==    by 0x41E75B: _ZSt11make_sharedI12c_pixel_imagoIEESt10shared_ptrIT_EDpOT0_ (shared_ptr.h:615)
==7252==    by 0x412665: c_imago::import(std::string, std::string, double) (imago.h:92)
==7252==    by 0x4120CC: c_imago::getd2(std::string) (imago.h:48)
==7252==    by 0x41A2FE: c_xcol_job::launch() (xcol_job.h:42)
==7252==    by 0x41B96D: main (worker.cpp:142)
=
```

How can I solve the memory leak?

Comment: can we see c_pixel_imago ?

Comment: How is `pixel` allocated?

Comment: @0x499602D2 So? This has little effect on `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Angew Yeah I thought so.

Comment: class c_pixel_imago : public c_pixel {
        public:
        double v[2];
    ...

Comment: @Medicalphysicist update the code in the post plz, not as comment

Comment: what is the v in px_buffer->v[0] ?

Comment: @fatih_k a double as it is declared in c_pixel_imago

Comment: is it double  or double array?

Comment: @fatih_k v is an array with two elements double.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the relation between `c_job` and `c_xcol_job` is.  Particularly whether it has a virtual destructor or not.

Comment: Does `c_pixel` and `c_pixel_imago` have a `virtual` destructor?

Comment: I didn't declare any (virtual or not virtual) destructor because I believed that unique_ptr or shared_ptr don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   unique_ptr<c_job> job;
...(loop)
    job.reset(new c_xcol_job);
...(end loop)
...
```

Did you declare c_job's destructor virtual? If not, it will not call the destructor of the c_xcol_job.

Comment: Are there any virtual functions in those classes?

Answer (score 0):

if member `v` is a dynamically allocated array and you do not `delete []` it in the destructor of `c_pixel_imago` you may get memory leak

Comment: The vector of shared pointers is defined in class c_imago as: vector<shared_ptr<c_pixel>> pixel; This class is defined in class c_pack as: shared_ptr<c_imago> ref;

Comment: @Medical physicist, how is class c_pixel defined?